# If $G$ is a group of order $12$ with $4$ $3$-Sylow, why $G$ can't have a subgroup of order $6$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I have to solve an exercise, where the hint is to prove that:

> If $G$ is a group of order $12$ with $4$ $3$-Sylow, why $G$ can't have a subgroup of order $6$?

I don't understand how I can conclude this.

Comment: How about $D_6$?

Comment: The subgroup of $D_6$ generated by $\langle a^2 ,b\rangle$ has order $6$?

Comment: Sorry I edit my question.

Comment: Suppose, $H\le G$ and $|H|=6$

Then, $[G:H]=2$ 

$\implies H\lhd G$

Then the factor group $G/H$ exists and is of order $2$.

 $\forall a\in G \implies (aH) ^2=H$

i.e $a^2\in H$

Suppose $a$ be an element of order $3$, then $a^3 =e \implies a^4=a$

Hence, $a=(a^2)^2 \in H$

Given $G$ has $4$ sylow $3$ subgroup. 

Hence, $G$ contains atleast $4\times 2=8$ elements of order $3$ and all are in $H$ i.e $|H|\ge 8$ , which is a contradiction. 

Hence, $G$ can't have a subgroup of order $6$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If $H\leq G$ is a subgroup of order $6$ then it is normal in $G$, because it has index $2$. It contains some $3$-Sylow subgroup. Since the $3$-Sylow subgroups are conjugate and $H$ is normal it follows that $H$ contains all four $3$-Sylow subgroups. This is obviously a contradiction, as $H$ has only $6$ elements.

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.